# How to store a newly created element to localStorage or Cookie with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, cookies, onclick, local-storage

I am making an idle clicker game for fun, everything was going fine until I encountered a problem.

What I basically want to happen is when the image is clicked and the clickCounter element is over one, the new image element is created. No problem here, the main problem is saving the image. If the user refreshes the page, I want the **created element to still be there**. I have tried using **outerHTML** and following some other Stack Overflow forum questions but I could never get a proper solution to this certain problem. I have also tried **localStorage** and **cookies** but I believe I am using them wrong.

My code is below, my sololearn will be linked below, consisting of the full code to my project.

```
 function oneHundThou() {

   var countvar = document.getElementById("clickCounter")
    if(document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML > 1) {
      alert("Achievement! 1 pat!")
      
      var achievement1k = document.createElement("img");
     

      // create a cookie so when the user refreshes the page, the achievement is shown again 

      document.cookie = "achievement1k=true";
      achievement1k.src = "https://c.pxhere.com/images/f2/ec/a3fcfba7993c96fe881024fe21e7-1460589.jpg!d";
      
      achievement1k.style.height = "1000px"
      achievement1k.style.width = "1000px"
      achievement1k.style.backgroundColor = "red"
      
      document.body.appendChild(achievement1k);
      oneHundThou = function(){}; // emptying my function after it is run once instead of using a standard switch statement
    }
    else {
      return
    }

  }
  oneHundThou();
```

I am aware that there is another post that is similar to this, however, my answer could not be answered on that post.

Full code is here: **https://code.sololearn.com/Wwdw59oenFqB**
Please help! Thank you. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the image, try storing the `innerHTML`, then create the image on document load:

```
function oneHundThou() {
  countvar.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('clickCount') ? localStorage.getItem('clickCount') : 0; //before if
  //original code
  localStorage.setItem('clickCount', countvar.innerHTML); //instead of doc.cookie
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    oneHundThou();
});
```

or, if you don't care that clickCounter may initialize to `null`, you can remove the `? :` and just put

```
countvar.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('clickCount');
```

Edit: shortened code with the `countvar` variable

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding and giving an answer to this question. Though, I tried doing this and for some reason it made the original click counter not work and even though the image has been clicked, it is not shown and says "0 pats". There is no error in console

Comment: Try putting `countvar.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('clickCount')` in the event listener instead of the function.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, thought the functionality for the website still works, the image is not saved.